# Bitcoin-Qt [0.8+] can read the blockchain. How can I? (and make it human readable)

Tags: blockchain

Most questions answer this about the old 0.7 version of keeping the blockchain. 0.8 changed to leveldb instead of berkeleydb from what I've read, and obviously Bitcoin-Qt is able to read it. For a project though, I want to read each block, and in in turn process each transaction. How would I go about actually reading the data in these blocks? Maybe as JSON or some other human-readable format.

Thanks in advance for any help. I've googled too much and just figured I'd ask the question instead of looking for an answer elsewhere that will likely end up being a good answer for 0.7 and earlier.

Comment: So the answers there may have become outdated, but the question is the same.

Comment: Yes. same question. The solutions that apply to BerkeleyDB are not applicable to leveldb. I have yet to find a way to query or otherwise read anything from a leveldb and that is what prompted asking it again. Hopefully we'll have an answer that is googlable for 0.8+.